# Odd issue when using Oracle UDT in ODP.NET (user defined type)

Tags: oracle, odp.net, user-defined-types

Oracle 11g.

I ran into an odd issue when using UDT, I have these 4 schemas: USER_1, USER_2, USER_A, USER_B.
Both USER_1 and USER_2 have an UDT (actually a nested table):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TAB_NUMBERS AS TABLE OF NUMBER(10)
```

USER_A has a synonym points to the type in USER_1:

```
create or replace synonym TAB_NUMBERS for USER_1.TAB_NUMBERS;
```

USER_B has a synonym points to the type in USER_2:

```
create or replace synonym TAB_NUMBERS for USER_2.TAB_NUMBERS;
```

Both USER_A and USER_B have a procedure which uses the synonym:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_test (p1 in tab_numbers)
IS
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
```

And in the C# code:

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("data source=mh;user id=USER_A;password=...");
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "proc_test";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
//
OracleParameter op = new OracleParameter();
op.ParameterName = "p1";
op.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
op.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Object;
op.UdtTypeName = "TAB_NUMBERS";
Nested_Tab_Mapping_To_Object nt = new Nested_Tab_Mapping_To_Object();
nt.container = new decimal[] { 1, 2 };
op.Value = nt;
......
```

This code works fine, but it raises an error when I change the connection string from USER_A to USER_B, the error says:

```
OCI-22303: type ""."TAB_NUMBERS" not found
```

Interestingly, if I change op.UdtTypeName = "TAB_NUMBERS"; to op.UdtTypeName = "USER_2.TAB_NUMBERS", the error is gone, and everything works fine.

Anyone has any clues?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: under user_b run select * from all_objects where object_name = 'TAB_NUMBERS'

Answer (score 0):

Custom type mappings cannot be specified using synonyms, regardless of whether or not the mapping is provided through the OracleCustomTypeMappingAttribute object or the XML configuration file.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/featUDTs.htm#ODPNT382